# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions;

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am getting this error all of a sudden. I did not delete any file.

What i did was, I checked out out a `github` branch (i worked on the branch 2 weeks back. it was working fine then), made some modifications in `3.json`. I changed the `gradle` from default to local distribution since i was getting - the specified `gradle` distribution does not appear to contain a `gradle` distribution. Then committed the code. Rebased it with development branch. Then when I run it, i got this error. Then i checked out the development branch. Again i got the same error. My team mates are not getting this error. So it is evident that the code is correct.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:1050)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /data/app/com.zopsmart.picking-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:1050) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7160 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        multiDexEnabled true


        buildConfigField("String", "host", "\"https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/\"")
    }

    /*splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
            universalApk true
        }
    }*/

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '.so'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // Constraint Layout
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    // Room Database
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0"
    // Dagger 2 Dependency Injection
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    // CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    // RxJava support for Room (use 1.1.0-alpha1 for latest alpha)
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0'
    // ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    // RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    // Add Dagger dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    //Circle IV library
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //Navigation Drawe
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    // GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    // OkHttpClient
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    // Zxing for scanning
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    // EPSON printer
    implementation files('libs/ePOS2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ePOSEasySelect.jar')
    //crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    // WorkManager
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha09'
    // Bugsnag
    implementation 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:4.+'
    implementation files('libs/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="XXXXXXXXXX">
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:name=".XXXXXXXXXX"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_circle"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The issue is with multidex configuration. Configure properly.

Comment: @Jaymin multiDexEnabled true - is already added in app level gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in manifiest file inside application tag.

```
<application>
.....
.....

<uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

</application>
```

Comment: Solved Your problem?

Comment: Bro check your code set all this very care fully becasue these type error with solve by my answer or multi dex enable .so you have to check it again

Comment: i have edited the question. gradle file and manifest file contents are displayed. Thanks for your interest. I have replaced few original text with XXXXXX since this is my company code and i cannot disclose all details

Comment: bro also add multi dex library in dependencies

Comment: i added your answer. it did not solve my problem. i have mentioned it in my first comment. but then i added multi dex library in dependencies. it solved my problem. thankyou for showing interest sparing your precious time. without you i wouldn't have solved this issue. thank you again.

Comment: i am not marking your answer as the solution. but i want to do something. i am new to stack overflow. is there something like giving you a credit or point or like your post or something that would benefit you. because i want to thank you in some way

Comment: the up arrow. am i right? it is recorded. but not displayed